# Count distinct values in a stream pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I have a pipeline that looks like

```
pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.read.subscription("some subscription"))
            .apply(Window.into(SlidingWindow.of(10 mins).every(20 seconds)
                            .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                    .plusDelayOf(20 seconds))
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                    .accumulatingFiredPanes()))
            .apply(RemoveDuplicates.create())
            .apply(Window.discardingFiredPanes()) // this is suggested in the warnings under https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/triggers#window-accumulation-modes
            .apply(Count.<String>globally().withoutDefaults())
```

This pipeline overcounts distinct values significantly (20x normal value). Initially, I was suspecting that the default trigger may have caused this issue. I have tweaked to use triggers that allow no lateness/discard fired panes/use processing time, all of which have similar overcount issues.

I've also tried `ApproximateUnique.globally`: it failed during pipeline construction because of an exception that looks like
`Default values are not supported in Combine.globally() if the output PCollection is not windowed by GlobalWindows.` There seems no way to add `withoutDefaults` to it (like we did with `Count.globally`).

Is there a recommended way to do `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in dataflow/beam streaming pipeline with reasonable precision?

P.S. I'm using Java Dataflow SDK 1.9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks OK; it shouldn't overcount. Note that you are placing each element into 30 windows, so if you have a window-unaware sink (equivalent to collapsing all the sliding windows) you would expect precisely 30 times as many elements. If you could show a bit more of the pipeline or how you are observing the counts, that might help.

Beyond that, I have a few suggestions for the pipeline:

- I suggest changing your trigger for `RemoveDuplicates` to `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)`; this will get you the same result at lower latency, since later elements arriving will have no impact. This trigger, and your current trigger, will never fire repeatedly. So it does not actually matter whether you set `accumulatingFiredPanes()` or `discardingFiredPanes()`. This is good, because neither one would work with the rest of your pipeline.
- I'd install a new trigger prior to the `Count`. The reason is a bit technical, but I'll try to describe it:

  - In your current pipeline, the trigger installed there (the "continuation trigger" of the trigger for `RemoveDuplicates`) notes the arrival time of the first element and waits until it has received all elements that were produced at or before that *processing time*, as measured by the upstream worker. There is some nondeterminism because it puns the local processing time and the processing time of other workers.
  - If you take my advice and switch the trigger for `RemoveDuplicates`, then the continuation trigger will be `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)` so it will always emit a count as soon as possible and then discard further data, which is very wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use graphite to observe the counts and I'm still investigating what could go wrong there. For your first point: will `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)` downcount? Given this trigger will emit windows whenever there's at least one element, so `RemoveDuplicate` will just have one element most of the time?

Comment: If you used `Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))`, then you would receive many outputs of mostly just one element. But with just `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))` it will shut down the window after the first time it outputs, discarding the rest of the input for that key.